# What is the meaning of the union of ascending chain $\bigcup_{k} N_{k}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

With $A\in \operatorname{End}(V)$ and $N(A^k)$ the nullspace of $A^k$, what does the 'union of ascending chain' mean, defined by:
$$\bigcup_{k} N(A^k)$$
I would assume that it means:
$$N(A)\cup N(A^2)\cup...\cup\ N(A^k)$$
Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, except that this union may run over more indices, perhaps infinitely many. More generally,

$$ x\in\bigcup_{i\in I} X_i\iff \exists i\in I\colon x\in X_i.$$

Here, presumably $\bigcup_k$ is short for $\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}$.